# C programming Strings printing

Tags: c, c99, c89

I have a question on this string .

for example:

```
char ex1[20]="Hello hi";
int choose;
scanf("%d",&choose);
```

What should I do to make it print "hi" when user enters `1` and "hello" would be printed if he enters `0`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at using the strtok function to tokenize ex1 into two separate strings?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `if` statement?

Comment: By defining the two words separately in an array. `char ex2 [2][20] = {"Hello", "hi"};`

Comment: @bruceg    i dont how i can use strok because my array has more than 200 sentences and program goes line by line ask for position of the word if  enter  1 then i would use strok to remove hi .

Comment: @WeatherVane i cannot split  the one array in to two arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void split(char*str, char** arr) {
    char* str2 = strstr(str, " ");
    *str2 = '\0';
    str2++;
    arr[0] = str;
    arr[1] = str2;
}
int main(void) {
    char ex1[20] = "Hello hi";

    char*arr[2];
    split(ex1, arr);

    int choose;
    scanf("%d", &choose);
    switch (choose) {
    case 0:
        puts(arr[0]);
        break;
    case 1:
        puts(arr[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The results are as follows

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes something like this but i have more than  200 lines  but thank you i will use strstr function .

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be:

```
if(choose == 1)
    printf("Hello\n");
else if(choose == 0)
    printf("hi\n");
else
    printf("Please enter 1 or 0.\n");
```

You don't need `ex1` here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

```
char buf[2];
fgets(buf, 2, stdin);
*buf == '1' ? puts("hi") : puts("hello");
```

This reads the first two characters from `stdin`, the standard input stream, and then prints "hi" if the first character is 1, or "hello" otherwise.

Comment: You have two `puts` and I prefer merging them: `puts(*buf == '1' ? "hi" : "hello");`

Comment: This read the first one character (not two) because terminating null-character have to be stored in `buf`.

Comment: `*buf == '1' ? puts("hi") : puts("hello");` - you should fire whoever writes code like this instead of using an `if` statement.

Comment: Why? It's not like I'm nesting `? :` operators. @immibis

Comment: @stackptr Because it's less readable than it could be easily. And in fact you put in *more work* to make it less readable!

Comment: Was it you who downvoted? @immibis And how is it more work to use `? :` instead of `if else`